# Phonegap- trigger a call to javascript from ios while app enterintobackground

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a phonegap application and want to call javascript function while the app enter into background to perform a webservice call to update the app status.For that i am using **writejavascript** function.But it didn't call that function.I don't know whether it is possible or not.
If possible just give me an idea to do this stuff.Thanks in advance.

NSString *tojs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"downloadMgr.updateStatus('%d');",status];

[self writeJavascript:tojs];

Answer (score 3):

Use Phonegaps event 'pause' and resume i think this may help you.
Eg:

```
 document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

  function onPause() {
  // Handle the pause event
  }
```

[Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause)

Full Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Cordova Pause Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.



function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

}

  function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
  }
// Handle the pause event
//
function onPause() {
}

 </script> </head> <body onload="onLoad()"></body> </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea Arjun.It's really helpfull for me, but inside onPause method the AJAX request was not called. when the app switching from background to foreground those Ajax webservice are executed.

Answer (score 0):

The pause event is not a lot of use on IOS:-

In the pause handler, any calls that go through Objective-C will not work, nor will any calls that are interactive, like alerts. This means that you cannot call console.log (and its variants), or any calls from Plugins or the PhoneGap API. These will only be processed when the app resumes (processed on the next run-loop).